# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.setWriteTimeout(I)Lcom/google/api/client/http/HttpRequest

Tags: dependencies, conflicting-libraries, apache-beam

I have updated `apache-beam-sdk` from `2.18 to 2.23` and using `guava library 29.0-jre` while running the dataflow i am getting the following error.

I have gone through some git hub links and tried to fix but, it doesn't seems to work.

Any help will be appriciated

Thanks!!!

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to construct instance from factory method DataflowRunner#fromOptions(interface org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptions)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.InstanceBuilder.buildFromMethod(InstanceBuilder.java:224)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.InstanceBuilder.build(InstanceBuilder.java:155)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.PipelineRunner.fromOptions(PipelineRunner.java:55)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.create(Pipeline.java:149)
        at mcc.analytics.transfer.BigQueryToTeradataPipeline$.delayedEndpoint$mcc$analytics$transfer$BigQueryToTeradataPipeline$1(BigQueryToTeradataPipeline.scala:146)
        at mcc.analytics.transfer.BigQueryToTeradataPipeline$delayedInit$body.apply(BigQueryToTeradataPipeline.scala:142)
        at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:34)
        at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
        at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
        at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
        at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:35)
        at scala.App$class.main(App.scala:76)
        at mcc.analytics.transfer.BigQueryToTeradataPipeline$.main(BigQueryToTeradataPipeline.scala:142)
        at mcc.analytics.transfer.BigQueryToTeradataPipeline.main(BigQueryToTeradataPipeline.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.InstanceBuilder.buildFromMethod(InstanceBuilder.java:214)
        ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.setWriteTimeout(I)Lcom/google/api/client/http/HttpRequest;
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.util.RetryHttpRequestInitializer.initialize(RetryHttpRequestInitializer.java:253)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.util.ChainingHttpRequestInitializer.initialize(ChainingHttpRequestInitializer.java:52)
        at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestFactory.buildRequest(HttpRequestFactory.java:93)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.buildHttpRequest(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:423)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:542)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:475)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:592)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.util.ResilientOperation$AbstractGoogleClientRequestExecutor.call(ResilientOperation.java:171)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.util.ResilientOperation.retry(ResilientOperation.java:67)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.util.GcsUtil.getBucket(GcsUtil.java:521)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.util.GcsUtil.bucketAccessible(GcsUtil.java:509)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.util.GcsUtil.bucketAccessible(GcsUtil.java:482)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.storage.GcsPathValidator.verifyPathIsAccessible(GcsPathValidator.java:83)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.storage.GcsPathValidator.validateOutputFilePrefixSupported(GcsPathValidator.java:53)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.options.GcpOptions$GcpTempLocationFactory.create(GcpOptions.java:314)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.options.GcpOptions$GcpTempLocationFactory.create(GcpOptions.java:294)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.ProxyInvocationHandler.returnDefaultHelper(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:592)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.ProxyInvocationHandler.getDefault(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:533)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:158)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.getGcpTempLocation(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.DataflowRunner.fromOptions(DataflowRunner.java:269)
        ... 19 more
```